# sendmail can not relay from itself

Tags: centos, sendmail, smtp

I am running 3 centos 5.2 servers and I have configured the server for forward all messages to root to be emailed to me via .forward rule.

This is working fine on two of the servers but not on the third.

I have also tried copying the mail config files from the backup server and placing them on the file server and restarting sendmail. I also removed and reinstalled sendmail via yum but the results are the same.

I am not sure what the issue could be they are all standard centos installs.

Here is an example from the backup server which is working and the fileserver which isn't I am also going to include the mail log.

**good from backup server**

```
[root@backup ]# sendmail -v bernie@example.com < test.mail
bernie@example.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 backup.localhost ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.8/8.13.8; Fri, 16 Oct 2009 10:23:50 -0700
>>> EHLO backup.localhost
250-backup.localhost Hello backup.localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> MAIL From:<root@backup.localhost> SIZE=73
250 2.1.0 <root@backup.localhost>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<bernie@example.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <bernie@example.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
250 2.0.0 n9GHNoGC020924 Message accepted for delivery
bernie@example.com... Sent (n9GHNoGC020924 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 backup.localhost closing connection
```

**bad from file server**

```
[root@fileserver bernie]#  sendmail -v bernie@example.com < test.mail
bernie@example.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 fileserver.localhost ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.8/8.13.8; Fri, 16 Oct 2009 10:23:26 -0700
>>> EHLO fileserver.localhost
250-fileserver.localhost Hello fileserver.localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>>> MAIL From:<root@fileserver.localhost>
550 5.0.0 Access denied
root... Using cached ESMTP connection to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
>>> MAIL From:<>
550 5.0.0 Access denied
postmaster... Using cached ESMTP connection to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
>>> MAIL From:<>
550 5.0.0 Access denied
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 fileserver.localhost closing connection
```

**mail log**

```
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28059]: n9GHdDom028059: from=root, size=72, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<200910161739.n9GHdDom028059@fileserver.localhost>, relay=root@localhost
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28060]: n9GHdDwl028060: tcpwrappers (fileserver.localhost, 127.0.0.1) rejection
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28059]: n9GHdDom028059: to=bernie@example.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30072, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28059]: n9GHdDom028059: n9GHdDon028059: DSN: Service unavailable
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28059]: n9GHdDon028059: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31096, relay=[127.0.0.1], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28059]: n9GHdDon028059: n9GHdDoo028059: return to sender: Service unavailable
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28059]: n9GHdDoo028059: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=32120, relay=[127.0.0.1], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28059]: n9GHdDon028059: Losing ./qfn9GHdDon028059: savemail panic
Oct 16 10:39:13 fileserver sendmail[28059]: n9GHdDon028059: SYSERR(root): savemail: cannot save rejected email anywhere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not positive without more details, but I would be checking for permission problems on the volume sendmail is using for its mail queue.  Sendmail acts like it can't write anything, either incoming mails or bounces...
Also, here is a [link on savemail panic](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/savemail_panic_in_Sendmail.html) that discusses that your aliases file might need to be rebuilt.

Comment: Problem turned out to be a deny all in hosts.deny. I am not sure how that got added, but once I removed it sendmail was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have two seperate setups on your machines.
The first one that is functionable provides these services:

```
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
```

The fielserver machine only has:

```
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
```

So i guess the two configs differ or you missed a packed to install.

Look at both machines and verify you have all packets on system fileserver. Than try to use your conf from backup on fileserver. (Change only ip adress an hostname settings.)

btw. your .mc file from both machines may share some light on your problem :)

Also it is possible that a file which is referenced in the config is missing on fileserver. e.g. access or local-host-names. Or another thing could be, the files are existentm, but not in the right form. Some files need to be in hash format.
Use makemap hash filename < filename to create them.